# Selenium python website login

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying over the past few hours , without success , to make webdriver.Firefox() run properly. I reinstalled geckodriver and verified it was added to the path , i tried to use FirefoxBinary but it didn't help.
I could not find any solution , and I am not sure how to fix this , I would appreciate your help.
This is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://testweb.com")                    
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("extpatid")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("extpatpw")
username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
```

Below are the exceptions received when I tried to execute the script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./braude.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Python version :

```
# /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.12+
```

Comment: You can use the interactive recording feature of Selenium, and after you `save as` Python, looking at the resulting Python code may indicate what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have this line:
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
but it's completely unnecessary and likely related to your ultimate problem - a wrong version of the Firefox webdriver module.

Try Chrome and see how it reacts with that.

Comment: `[Errno 8] Exec format error` usually points to incorrect shebang line, using `Chrome` hardly can help in this case